# Scala package delcaration - one way causes package objects visible, other makes it not?

Tags: scala, package

In `foo/bar/my_package/package.scala`:

```
package foo.bar
package object my_package {
  type SomeType = java.lang.String
}
```

Then, in `foo/bar/my_package/my_sub/MyClass.scala`

```
package foo.bar.my_package.my_sub

class MyClass {
  var x: SomeType = _
}
```

This fails to compile; `SomeType` isn't found.  If I change `MyClass.scala` to

```
package foo.bar.my_package
package my_sub

class MyClass {
  var x: SomeType = _
}
```

Everything works fine.  What is the difference!?!??!

(This is Scala 2.8.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package declarations, like imports, give you access to everything inside them.  So when you

```
package foo.bar.my_package
```

then you have everything available that you would if you did

```
import foo.bar.my_package._
```

Furthermore, declaring a package on a single line means that everything below belongs to that package:

```
package foo.bar.my_package {
  package my_sub {
    class MyClass { var x: SomeType = _ }
  }
}
```

(which is equivalent to:

```
package foo.bar.my_package
package my_sub
class MyClass { var x: SomeType = _ }
```

)

so you can see how the contents of `foo.bar.my_package` ought to be in scope in this case.  In the other case, you only have the contents of `foo.bar.my_package.my_sub` available, which does not include `SomeType`.

Comment: Note that in my second example, I'm not using curly braces for the package stuff; is this just implied?

Comment: @davetron5000 It is not implied, it is just two different syntaxes for the very same thing. Rex is using curly braces to make it clear that `my_sub` is inside `foo.bar.my_package`. The important point, however, is that a `package` declaration imports everything at that point.

Comment: Edited the answer to make that clear.  I'll select this as the "right answer" if no one has a problem with my edit

Answer (score 2):

It's a visibility question.

```
package foo.bar.my_package.my_sub

class MyClass {
  var x: SomeType = _
}
```

When you declare `x`, the following things are visible:

- Every member of `MyClass`
- Everything inside `foo.bar.my_package.my_sub`
- Every member of `scala.Predef`
- Everything inside `scala`
- Everything inside `java.lang`

The type `SomeType` is not inside any of those.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
package foo.bar.my_package
package my_sub

class MyClass {
  var x: SomeType = _
}
```

Then the visibility is:

- Every member of `MyClass`
- Everything inside `foo.bar.my_package.my_sub`
- Everything inside `foo.bar.my_package`
- Every member of `scala.Predef`
- Everything inside `scala`
- Everything inside `java.lang`

And `SomeType` is inside `foo.bar.my_package`, which is the second line.

A related question is why it works this way. You can get a start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243794/what-are-the-biggest-differences-between-scala-2-8-and-scala-2-7/1245195#1245195), though there's a question precisely about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660806/whats-the-motive-behind-chained-package-clauses-in-scala). I don't much like the answer to that question, though, as it really doesn't touch the reasons for it. It does [link to a page](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/chained_package_clauses_in_scala.html) on scala-lang about new features of Scala 2.8, in which Odersky explains the reasons.