# Scala package style difference

Tags: scala

Scala `package` is cumulative, so `package a.b` can also be written as

```
package a
package b
```

Is there any difference between these or is it just a matter of programming style?

Comment: @SethTisue Sorry my mind wasn't working. I meant `package`, not `import`. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that with

```
package a
package b
```

everything from package `a` is in scope, not just from `a.b`.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer but also marked my question as dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660806/whats-the-motive-behind-chained-package-clauses-in-scala) as pointed out by Chris Martin.